# Add a definition into a command in python

Tags: python, command

I have c is a definition (code below). How can I add it to a command to run in python? Thank you.

```
text_file = open("lastline.txt", "w")
n = text_file.write(last_line)
text_file.close()

with open('lastline.txt', 'r') as f: 
      c = f.read(12)
print("Detected disk identifier as", c)
os.system("diskutil unmount c")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
os.system("diskutil unmount %s", c)
```

Answer (score 0):

for that you can use fstrings in python.

```
os.system(f"diskutil unmount {c}")
```

For older versions of python(below 3.6):

```
os.system("diskutil unmount {}".format(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple concatenation.  You have to convert your variable to string type.
Both of these are covered in any `str` tutorial.  To break this down into individual steps:

```
c_ctr = str(c)
cmd = "diskutil unmount " + c_str
os.system(cmd)
```

However, it is more "pythonic" to do this in one line, with string formatting, as the other answers show.

Comment: I'm glad you got what you needed.  Actually, my answer is over-simplified.  Once you understand these basic operations, you should combine them into the single-line form you see in the other posts.